# Rounded corners in a shape shows color when solid color is transparent

Tags: android, android-layout

If I use the following shape drawable

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:shape="rectangle">
    <stroke android:width="1dp" android:color="@android:color/black" />
    <corners android:radius="20dp" />
    <solid android:color="@android:color/transparent"/>
</shape>
```

Then the somehow the rounded corners ends up having a color (black-grey). The inside of the shape is transparent except where it is around the corners. When I set the solid color to white or black, then everything inside the border is per the color as expected.

My question is, why the rounded corners seem to show color when the solid color is transparent (or not even set)?

Thanks

Here is a picture of what I see
[image]

Comment: Please add the layout code where you have used this drawable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rounded corner showing color because you are using stroke width as `android:width="1dp"` and it is showing color that you have given to stroke.
So If you don not want border color then just remove following line  from your xml file

`<stroke android:width="1dp" android:color="@android:color/black" />`

or give width `0dp` to your stroke as follow

`<stroke android:width="0dp" android:color="@android:color/black" />`

I hope its work for You. Thanks

Comment: This is the stroke which shows the peremeter of the shape. Thats is fine. But what I am seeing is "areas" of colors.I will post a picture

Comment: @Snake In some cases in android studio it shows like you posted image but when you run it then u will find there is nothing like that

Comment: @Snake did you check this when you run app in your device